# Programmatically adding border container with other widgets inside a content pane

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm trying to add a border container with a center and right region inside of a center region content pane programmatically but the center and right regions overlap -- the content panes dont seem to be recognized as regions. This is the code:

javascript module that adds border container and content panes:

```
     define(["dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",       "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
   function (domConstruct, registry, BorderContainer, ContentPane
     ) {
    return {
        Test: function () {

           ...

            //border container
            var mainContainer = new BorderContainer({
                id: 'mainContainer',
                design: 'headline',
                style: "height: 500px; width: 800px;"
            });
            //center content pane -- > gets overwritten by the right content pane
            var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                id: 'centerContainer',
                region: "center",
                content: "I'm in the center"
            });
            //right content pane
            var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                id: 'rContainer',
                region: "right",
                content: " I'm on the right",
                style: "width: 100px"
            });
            mainContainer.addChild(cp1);
            mainContainer.addChild(cp2);
            mainContainer.placeAt('Content');
            mainContainer.startup();
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the center content pane where the border container and other content panes are being added to:

```
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" id="Main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="TOC" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'leading'">
 </div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="Content" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'center'">
 </div>
```

Comment: If I manually change the window size, the layout will appear correctly.  Maybe I need to resize the window somehow in code?

Answer (score 0):

I just added:

```
  mainContainer.resize();
```

right after:

```
  mainContainer.startup();
```

and it displays correctly now

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the first code block it looks like your problem is that you are calling startup() before the BorderContainer is attached to the document.

However, I don't understand your example code (the relation between the first code snippet and the second one), are you trying to do this declaratively (in markup) or programatically?

Comment: The first code snippet is a module that is programatically adding a border container with content panes into the main htm page (second code snippet) at the 'Content' div

Comment: Oh I see... seems like a bug then, assuming that you are calling parse() before the programmatic code above executes.   I don't see you calling parse() though.